# Apache Server SSL Problems

Tags: server, apache2, openssl

Hi There is this weird problem going on with putting ssl on the server I keep on getting this error in the terminal after I already created the .key and .crt files but it keeps on saying I placed the files in the conf.d directory and I already configured the  thing so there is something that I did wrong there I also used openssl to create a .key and the .crt files thanks for the help if anyone can

```
service apache2 reload
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/www.domainname.crt
Invalid command '-----BEGIN', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'conftest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Comment: This suggests the certificate is either invalid, or the server is missing certain modules. Try reading the Apache error log.

Answer (score 2):

Apache will treat files in `conf.d/` as config files, and the `.crt` file is not a valid apache config file.

Instead put them somewhere else and have the config file in `sites-enabled/` refer to them. The `default-ssl` config has the following in it:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

So put your certificate file in `/etc/ssl/certs/` and your key in `/etc/ssl/private/` and edit the config to have the correct file names.

You might also want to read the [official Ubuntu server guide about Apache and HTTPS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration) or just search google for more information.

Comment: :O That is how you do it